# exporting swf to mpeg

Tags: flash, export, mpeg

I am trying to export a .swf to mpg/avi or any other easily viewable and distributable format.

It has worked in the past but the .swf we are currently trying to export has more advanced filters and masks. Can any one tell me a good program/method?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I've always had decent luck with Flash's built in Export to movie option.  However, if the animations are inside a movie clip it tends to fail.  I've always copied and pasted the animation into a new document/stage, making sure that everything was on one timeline, and exported that way.  If you have the Perian codecs installed and you are on a Mac, you MIGHT be able to open SWF's inside of Quicktime Pro, Mpegstreamclip, or VLC Player.  If you're on PC, you might try the K-lite codec pack with Mpegstreamclip or VLC.  I haven't tried it, but it might be an option to experiment with.

One more thing, if you are exporting this for web I would recommend FLV's or .MOVs.  If you want it viewable on iPads and iPhones I would stick with H264 movs or m4vs.  Alternatively you could always export to whatever you want as your master, and then upload to Youtube and/or Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm led to believe this problem is greatly reduced by the newer versions of Flash. The best solution in the end was to find someone who had CS5.